# get id of Selected Tag

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, combobox, selectlist

how can i give Id of my selected tag in c#
this is my code:

```
Options = new SelectList(_db.CityUserTable, nameof(CityUserTable.CityID), nameof(CityUserTable.CityName));
            Options.First(x => x.Value == user.CityID.ToString()).Selected = true;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have it backwards. You're setting the property `Selected` true where `CityId` matches. Instead you need to get the `Value` (Assuming value contains the CityId) where `Selected` is true.

```
Options.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Selected)?.Value
```

Use `?` after `FirstOrDefault` to ensure a selected match was found before accessing `Value`.

Comment: thank you for answering but it show error....... 'SelectListItem' does not contain a definition for 'CityID' and no accessible extension method 'CityID' accepting a first argument of type 'SelectListItem' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @ Pilot Reza I updated my answer. Change `CityId` to `Value`.